# How to filter multiple criteria in a single column with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, filter

With Google Apps Script, I like to filter multiple criteria in a single column on a google sheet.  In the following simple example, I like to filter "Apple" and "blank" in Column A, in order to get the same filtering results as we do manually in the picture example below.  I couldn't figure it out in Google Apps Script.  My actual application deals with a huge number of data sets in a google sheet (100k rows). So I would appreciate any help for an efficient method!  Thank you!

```
function test() {

  var data = [['Fruits', 'Price'],
  ['Apple', 10],
  ['Orange', 5],
  ['', 30],
  ['Mango', 7]];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  ss.getRange('A1:B5').setValues(data);

  if (ss.getFilter() != null) {   //Remove existing fitler before creating a new filter
    ss.getFilter().remove();
  }
  var filter = ss.getRange('A1:B').createFilter();

  criteria = ['Apple', ''];
  filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberEqualToAny(criteria);
  // filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualToAny(criteria);  //didn't work
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, filterCriteria);
}
```

[image: Manual Filter Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied("=REGEXMATCH(A2:A5,  \"(Apple|^$)\" )")
```

This will use a regular expression that will check if the row contains **Apple** or an empty cell.

*Note: If you want to add more criteria, just add inside the open and close parenthesis `()` and separate it with `|`. Example `(Apple|Mango|^$)`*

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference

- [Filter.whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula)

Comment: Awesome!  It's working.  BTW, could you explain what ^$ is?   By trial and error I see it filters the blank out.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Newbie - You are correct. It is a regular expression to catch blank or empty cells. `^` matches the beginning of input while `&` matches the end of input. Since there is no character in between of `^` and `&` there is no character to match other than the empty cells. See [Regex Assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions)